# Android button refuses to reduce its size in a table?

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a button that is in a table, but the button stretches across the screen, thereby stretching my image, making it ugly.  I have tried wrap_content, fill_parent, and match_parent but they all give the same result.  Here is my xml.  Why doesn't  the button reduce it's size???

```
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >


                   <TableRow>
                     <ImageView
                             android:contentDescription="@string/contents"
                             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                             android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/lesson1" />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/alpha"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  </TableRow>


  <TableRow>
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:textStyle="italic"
          android:text="@string/alphanote"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  </TableRow>


  <TableRow>
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/directions2"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/Button1"
          android:layout_width="14dp"
          android:background="@drawable/playstart" />

  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView4"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/alpha1"
          />

      </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>     
     </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are bothering with `TableLayout` and `TableRow` if you only have one column. `TableLayout` is for a multi-column table.

That being said, you do not control the widths of columns in `TableLayout` via any of your mentioned approaches. Instead, use [`android:stretchColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns) and [`android:shrinkColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:shrinkColumns) on the `TableLayout` itself.

I'm not sure that will even work, as the point behind `TableLayout` is to try to best fill the rows to the width of the table. You should probably convert this to a simple vertical `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I need to use the scrollview and have my buttons side by side.

Comment: @user3623689: You do not have any buttons side by side. To have more than one column in a `TableLayout`, one or more `TableRow` elements need to have more than one child. All of your `TableRow` elements have one child, so you have just one column. Plus, you only have one button.